# Extracting key from TR31 encrypted key block in swift with KEK

Tags: swift, encryption, key, aes, unwrap

I am trying to implement this working python code in Swift. Basically it takes a TR31 key block and unwrap the key from it using a kek.  This is the working Python Code which gives the correct key in clear(f039121bec83d26b169bdcd5b22aaf8f):

```
kek = "89E88CF7931444F334BD7547FC3F380C"
encryptedTR31KeyBlock = "A0096K0TD12S0100KS1800604B120F929280000015BE1EA22731B03647031CEA17F516A5B7B14FC7D08BAA4377B803E1"
header, decryptedKey = tr31.unwrap(bytes.fromhex(kek), encryptedTR31KeyBlock)
print(decryptedKey.hex())
```

I tried the following in Swift but it is giving a CryptoKit.CryptoKitError.unwrapFailure:

```
let kekBytes2: [UInt8] = [
    0x89, 0xE8, 0x8C, 0xF7, 0x93, 0x14, 0x44, 0xF3,
    0x34, 0xBD, 0x75, 0x47, 0xFC, 0x3F, 0x38, 0x0C,
]

let kek = CryptoKit.SymmetricKey(data: Data(kekBytes2))

let encryptedTR31KeyBlock: [UInt8] = [
    0x15, 0xBE, 0x1E, 0xA2, 0x27, 0x31, 0xB0, 0x36,
    0x47, 0x03, 0x1C, 0xEA, 0x17, 0xF5, 0x16, 0xA5,
    0xB7, 0xB1, 0x4F, 0xC7, 0xD0, 0x8B, 0xAA, 0x43,
]
//unwrap key
let unwrappedKey2 = try AES.KeyWrap.unwrap(encryptedTR31KeyBlock, using: kek)
```

breakdown of the TR31 block:
A0096K0TD12S0100KS1800604B120F9292800000(header)
15BE1EA22731B03647031CEA17F516A5B7B14FC7D08BAA43(encrypted key)
77B803E1(MAC)

Answer (score 0):

I'm author of that Python library. When TR-31 key block is unwrapped, there is a lot more going on. And to describe it is to describe the entire TR-31 specification.

So, here what you are doing wrong:

1. TR-31 key block is not AES-wrapped as implemented by Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/aes/keywrap
2. The key block you got there uses (deprecated) variant-based DES method. Not AES.

You can look at what the library does and re-implement it faithfully in swift and it should work.

Comment: Is this the python library mentioned? https://github.com/knovichikhin/psec

Comment: Yes. Didn't want to advertise (people don't like that here).